# MVC3 ValidationFor on Input Tag (without EditorFor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I have an MVC3 page that is strongly typed with a IEnumerable which displays a list of Headers on the page.  At the top of the page though I want to have a small form that I can get some initial details (start date, end date) for a new Header and then ship those off to an Edit view.

I have this all working with the top form using

Next I wanted to add validation (basically start date and end date are required fields) and i was trying to use ValidationMessageFor and this is where things started to fall appart.  I tried to do a number of different ValidationMessageFor(x => (new Header().StartDate) and similar ... then went down the path of trying to change the

The problem seems to be that I can't add validation to an

Is there a recommended way to do something like this?  Is there a way to add validation to a

Comment: Theoretically you can use direct javascript validation if all you validating is date

Comment: shift the end/start date in another view and make its @model DateTime

Comment: I think the answer is going to be along the lines of creating a presentation object with a "New Header" and a "List of Headers" and then just using the validation as is, but was hoping there might be another way.  (like the javascript validation idea, but was hoping to just use what is available in MVC3)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is Html.BeginCollectionItem. Check out this: http://blog.codeville.net/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/